# more than 100MB video not playing in iphone

Tags: iphone, video

`i have django project where one page have video tag in that video will be plying it works well in android and desktop but in iphone not working when it's cross that file size >100MB

i just use this code`

```
<div class="video_merge_class" id="video_merge">
    <video id="video" preload="auto"  width="360px" height="350"  src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ABC_Consultancy/1705388734072114_record.mp4" style=" border: 1px solid black; background:white;" controls="controls" playsinline></video>
    
</div>
  <button onclick="play()"  >play</button>
<script>
    function play(){
    let vid = document.getElementById("video");
    vid.play();
    }
</script>
```